# How do I create a shortcut in VS 2019?

Tags: visual-studio

Visual Studio 2019 - creating shortcuts - In the past this sequence created shortcuts:

Tools => Options => Environment => Keyboard => Apply: Visual Studio Code => Edit.Copy => Use new shortcut in: Global => Ctrl-Insert => Assign.

This no longer works.  Ctrl-C still works.

How do I create a shortcut in VS 2019?

Comment: `How do I create a shortcut in VS 2019?` What results popped up when you pasted that into a search engine?

Comment: When I search, I get the same results as I have used in the past.  However, since the last VS update, this no longer works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to select **Text Editor** for **Use new shortcut in**.

Comment: After selecting  Tools => Options => Text Editor ... I do not see Use new shortcut in?

Comment: @ttom It is in Tools => Options => Environment => Keyboard, instead of Global scope, try to select Text Editor.